# How to get line items from Business Central Web Service (Odata)?

Tags: odata, dynamics-nav, dynamics-business-central

From Microsoft Documentation, to get salesOrderLines, the following http request is needed:

`GET businesscentralPrefix/companies({id})/salesOrders({id})/salesOrderLines({salesOrderLineId})`

However, it assumes each json object has a unique GUID. But when I try to get Odata, the only thing close to a unique id I get back is "@odata.etag", and this does not allow me to access the salesOrderLines.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using OData or API endpoint?

Comment: Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/api-reference/v1.0/api/dynamics_salesorderline_get

Comment: Have you tried the sales line no. eg. 10000 ?

Comment: @JeffUK I've tried different fields as the id, none of them works

Comment: @MakSim I am using ODatav4, is there a difference between that and API endpoint (I assumed it's the same thing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/salesOrders?$expand=SalesOrderSalesLines`